# Why must the stress-energy tensor be traceless in 2D classical general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, spacetime-dimensions, trace

It's easy to show that the Einstein tensor is always traceless in 1+1 spacetime dimensions; this is just a simple algebraic identity that follows directly from the definitions. The Einstein field equations then imply that the stress-energy tensor must be traceless as well.

But this seems weird to me. What's stopping us from considering a massive scalar field? Or a perfect fluid with a pressure that's different from its density? These seem like perfectly physically reasonable stress-energy configurations, but general relativity doesn't seem to allow them. (I'm just talking about classical GR, so there shouldn't be any issues of renormalizability.)

Comment: Not only is it traceless, it's identically zero actually. This is because $\int \sqrt{g} R$ is a topological quantity in 2D (related to the Euler characteristic).

Comment: @Prahar Hm, I had not realized that. But now that I think about it, intrinsic curvature in 2D is characterized by a single local degree of freedom ($R$), so I guess it makes sense that $R_{\mu \nu}$ must be proportional to $R g_{\mu \nu}$. So is the solution just that the standard Einstein field equations don't work as a theory of gravity in 2D, and we need to consider more complicated field equations?

Comment: Yes. There are no gravitational d.o.f. in 2D (and 3D). Everything is topological. Indeed, because it is topological, there is no way to couple any matter d.o.f. locally to gravity.

Comment: @Prahar In 3D there are no vacuum degrees of freedom (the Weyl tensor vanishes), but there's still a nontrivial Ricci tensor, right? Can't you have nontrivial local dynamics within an extended body of stress-energy?

Comment: The tracefree part of the Riemann tensor (Weyl) vanishes and the trace part (Ricci tensor) is completely fixed in terms of the matter stress tensor. Consequently, the gravitational d.o.f. is entirely determined by the matter dynamics. There is no freedom for gravity to do anything other than what is dictated by matter.

Comment: @Prahar I don't understand exactly what you mean by that. In any number of dimensions, the metric is determined by the stress-energy tensor plus appropriate boundary conditions. Are you claiming that in 3D you can't specify boundary conditions? Or that the Ricci tensor is fixed determined *locally* by the stress-energy tensor, without needing to solve any differential equations or do any nonlocal integrals?

Comment: I agree that if extended object A and extended object B are completely separated by vacuum, then they can't influence each other gravitationally in 3D. But it seems to me that you could still have nontrivial gravitational dynamics within a single extended object.

Comment: When people talk about nontrivial gravity theories in $1+1$ dimensions (e.g. admitting black holes) they usually mean *dilaton* gravities. See [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0604049) for an introduction.

Comment: @tparker It is from 1977 but still valid and interesting to read: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243488913_General_relativity_in_two-_and_three-dimensional_space-times. Maybe it helps to get answer to your question.

Comment: Permalink: https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.11057